# server responding with error but the data goes to database expressjs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, knex.js

I have a form for an ecom website with two button one for card payment and the second is for cash on delivery , when I send the data from the frontend the data goes to the database despite the network it shows me  2 error the first one is the 'no data to load' and the second one is  'unable to order2' but I didn't know where the fault came from (I'm using knex as package)

```
 const handleOrderCOD = (req,res, db) => {
    const {firstname, lastname, email, mobilenumber, adress, city, size, quantity} = req.body;
    if(!firstname || !lastname || !email || !mobilenumber || !adress || !city)
        {return  res.status(400).json('no data to load')};
    db.insert({
            
            firstname: firstname,
            lastname:lastname,
            email:email,
            mobilenumber:mobilenumber,
            adress:adress,
            city:city,
            size:size,
            quantity:quantity,
            joined: new Date()
    
           
        
        })
    
    .into('orders')
    
    
        .then(user =>{
            if(user){
                 return res.json(user[0])   
            } else{
                res.status(400).json('unable to order1')
            }
    
        })
        .catch(err=>res.status(400).json('unable to order2'))
    }
    
     const handleOrderCP = (req,res, db) => {
    const {firstname, lastname, email, mobilenumber, adress, city, size, quantity} = req.body;
    if(!firstname || !lastname || !email || !mobilenumber || !adress || !city)
        {return  res.status(400).json('no data to load')};
    db.insert({
            
            firstname: firstname,
            lastname:lastname,
            email:email,
            mobilenumber:mobilenumber,
            adress:adress,
            city:city,
            size:size,
            quantity:quantity,
            joined: new Date()
    
           
        
        })
    
    .into('orderscp')
    
    
        .then(user =>{
            console.log(user)
            if(user){
                 return res.json(user[0])   
            } else{
                res.status(400).json('unable to order1')
            }
    
        })
        .catch(err=>res.status(400).json('unable to order2'))
    }
    
    
    
        

    
    
        
    
    module.exports={
        handleOrderCOD,
        handleOrderCP
    }
```

Comment: You use an object-relational mapping package (ORM) here, but you didn't mention which one. Sequelize? TypeORM?  Please [edit] your question to tell us.

Comment: im using knex @O.Jones